# Вместо POST запроса выполняется GET

Tags: django, http, post, get

```
HTML код


{% extends 'index.html' %}


{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <div class="post">
                <form method="post" class="post-form">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p}}
                    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="btn btn-primary float-right" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

{% endblock %}



views.py код

    class UpdateProfile(UpdateView):
        model = SiteUser
        template_name = 'profile.html'
        fields = ['INN']
        success_url = reverse_lazy('info')

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(UpdateProfile, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['site_user'] = SiteUser.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
            return context
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас форма внутри формы. По-умолчанию форма всегда отправляет GET.

думаю так будет правильнее

```
 {% block content %}
    <div class="container">
            <div class="post">
                <form method="post" class="post-form">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p}}
                    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="btn btn-primary float-right" />
                </form>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: У вас форма была обёрнута в другую форму. Смотрите внимательнее.

Comment: Спасибо, я просто только начал этим заниматься, прошу прощения за код